# Vanilla JS budget app every item added adds previous item from Array

Tags: javascript

When a user enters a title and amount, it gets pushed to an array. If the item is an expense, it gets pushed to an expense array of objects, if it's an income, it gets pushed to an income array of objects. Then either the displayIncome or displayExpense functions render a component so that it's displayed. The issue that i'm having is that every time I press the submit button, the app displays the previous item as one item and also the previous item with the new item as another individual item. If there are two items in the array, the app will display (item1) ((item1) + (item2)). The picture shows my issue. How do I get the app to only display one item for each item in the array?

```
let expense_list = []

let income_list = []

addExpense.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    if(expenseTitle.value == '' || expenseAmount.value == ''){
                return;   
            }
            let expense = {
                type: 'expense',
                title: expenseTitle.value,
               amount: expenseAmount.value,
               id: Date.now()
            }
            expense_list.push(expense)
            console.log(expense_list)
            
            clearExpense()
            displayExpense()          
})

addIncome.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    if(incomeTitle.value == '' || incomeAmount.value == ''){
        return;   
    }
    let income = {
        type: 'income',
        title: incomeTitle.value,
       amount: incomeAmount.value,
       id: Date.now()
    }
    income_list.push(income)
    console.log(income_list)
    clearIncome()
    displayIncome()  
})

const clearExpense = () =>{
    expenseTitle.value = '';
    expenseAmount.value = '';
}
const clearIncome = () =>{
    incomeTitle.value = ''
    incomeAmount.value = ''
}

const displayExpense = () =>{
    expense_list.map((entry) =>{
        return expenseList.innerHTML += `<li id = "${entry.id}" class= "${entry.type}">
        <div class = "entry">${entry.title}: $${entry.amount}</div>
        <div class="icon-container">
        <div class = "edit" id="${entry.id}"></div>
        <div class ="delete" id="${entry.id}"></div>
        </div>
        </li>`       
    })
}

const displayIncome = () =>{
    income_list.map((entry) =>{
        return incomeList.innerHTML += `<li id = "${entry.id}" class= "${entry.type}">
        <div class = "entry">${entry.title}: $${entry.amount}</div>
        <div class="icon-container">
        <div class = "edit" id="${entry.id}"></div>
        <div class ="delete" id="${entry.id}"></div>
        </div>
        </li>`
    })
}
```

[image]

I've tried just using one array for expenses and incomes, and using forEach but every time I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the expenseList.innerHTML before mapping.

Something like that

```
const displayExpense = () =>{
    expenseList.innerHTML = ''
    expense_list.map((entry) =>{ ....
```